# Grails 3 fields plugin custom templates

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-3.0

Is it possible to customize [grails-plugin-fields](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/fields) templates to override default f:table and f:all templates?

I've tried placing a custom `_table.gsp` file inside my application `grails-app/views/templates/_fields/` and `src/main/templates/_fields/` but it doesn't works.

From the [plugin source code](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/fields/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/grails/plugin/formfields/FormFieldsTagLib.groovy#L197) seems that this is the right place to create this file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with you. I worked it out by placing `_table.gsp` in `/grails-app/views/templates/_fields/`. I tried to place it in `/src/templates/_fields/` but didn't work. Here's the proof.

[image]

I'm using grails 3.0.7 and testing this by using `grails run-app` command, by the way.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey @Iqbal, I am new to grails. Could you give example how to override f:all? I want to remove f:all, with custom materializecss. So that when I am confident about my domain class and deecide to generate views for domain class, it will generate with proper design using materialize css. In grails 2 there was _form.gsp which was useful. Could you please give some example how to achieve this?